# Dante server custom authentication

Tags: dante

Is there any way in Dante that I can create my own authentication script? Take this squid configuration for example:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/bin/python /etc/auth.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use socksmethod=pam.username in config and develop your own pam module.

Comment: Perhaps an example share or a relevant reference would significantly support the answer.

Comment: Sure, bottom of page https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/latest/config/auth_pam.html has more details. Then write and add a pam auth module to your box. example in go: https://github.com/msteinert/pam